# To count the occurrences of a particular word in the linked list of strings. how can it be done in log(n) time?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a SORTED singly linked list of strings. I need to find occurrences of a particular string in the list. How can I do it in logarithmic time?

Comment: I suspect you can only do it if the list is ordered.

Comment: If your data-structure is a linked list, you are SOL from the start. It does not matter whether it is sorted.

Comment: It is not what I have chosen but i have been told to do so..

Comment: `It is not what I have chosen but i have been told to do so`  Then ask the instructor to stop messing around with your sanity and ask for an assignment that is actually possible.  A linked list must be traversed to get to a certain element.  That traversal is O(N) right from the start.  So there goes your assignment's requirements, right down the drain.

Comment: See here for a bit more discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281053/how-to-apply-binary-search-olog-n-on-a-sorted-linked-list.

Comment: I have freedom to create a linked list the way I want. I was thinking of sorting it while creating and then apply search. Any other approach that would help me finding the occurrences would help.

Comment: _'I have freedom to create a linked list the way I want'_ Use `std::list` then. To achieve O(log(N)) though, other containers like e.g. [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/hash_function) along with a hash might get you better results.

Answer (score 5):

Not. Lists support only linear access, and since your string can be anywhere you must check O(N) elements.