# Search Function in Linked List - C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

My aim is to produce a function that searches for a number already in the list and print that it has been found.
My initial idea was to follow my remove function which searches through the list until it finds a number (to then delete).
This seemed the logical way to code the search function. If this isn't correct how would I modify it to search through my list and display that a number has been found?
I have nodes *head, *current and *temp as well as node pointer **next** and **number** as the data type in a class on a .h file.
Thank you.
**NOTE** - I used my remove() function under the search() function.

```
#include <iostream>                                                 
#include <string>                                                   
#include <fstream>                                                  
#include "LinkedList.h"

using namespace SDI;

int main()
{
    LinkedList menu;

    menu.insert(5);                     
    menu.insert(4);
    menu.insert(2);
    menu.insert(3);
    menu.insert(8);
    menu.remove(4);
    menu.reverse();
    menu.display();
    menu.search(2);
    system("pause");

};


LinkedList::LinkedList()            
{
    head = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
};


LinkedList::~LinkedList()           
{

};


void LinkedList::insert(int add)                                    //insert function, data is stored in add from function body
{
    Node* newnode = new Node;                                       //definition of add node, make new node and make node* point to it
    newnode->next = NULL;                                           //point and set up to last node in the list (nothing)
    newnode->number = add;                                          //adds data to list

    if (head != NULL)                                               //if head is pointing to object then we have list
    {
        current = head;                                             //make current pointer point to head
        while (current->next != NULL)                               //check to see if end at list, is it the last node?
        {
            current = current->next;                                //advances current pointer to end of list
        }
        current->next = newnode;                                    //adds new node next to value already stored
    }
    else
    {
        head = newnode;                                             //if we don't have element in list
    }
};


void LinkedList::remove(int remove)                                 //remove function, data is stored in remove from function body
{
    Node* remove1 = NULL;                                           //searches through for same value in remove and deletes
    temp = head;
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL && current->number != remove)            //check if current node is one we want to delete...if not advance current pointer to next one
    {
        temp = current;                                             //keep temp pointer one step behind
        current = current->next;                                    //advance to next node, traverse list till at the end
    }
    if (current == NULL)                                            //pass through whole list and value not found
    {
        std::cout << "N/A\n";
        delete remove1;                                             //removes spare number floating around in memory
    }
    else
    {
        remove1 = current;                                          //pointing to value we want to delete
        current = current->next;                                    //advances current pointer to next node
        temp->next = current;                                       //stops hole that occurs in list, patches this up
        if (remove1 == head)                                        //if pointer is pointing to front of list
        {
            head = head->next;                                      //advance the head to next
            temp = NULL;
        }

        delete remove1;
    }
};


void LinkedList::search(int searchNum)
{
    Node* searchnumber = nullptr;
    temp = head;
    current = head;

    while (current != NULL && current->number != searchNum)
    {
        temp = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (current != NULL)
    {
        searchnumber = current;
        current = current->next;
        std::cout << "-" << searchnumber << " Found";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "N/A";
    }
};


void LinkedList::display()
{
    current = head;                                                 //point to start of list

    while (current != NULL)                                         //while it points to something in list
    {
        std::cout << current->number;                               //display list starting from start
        current = current->next;                                    //advance to next pointer
    }
};


void LinkedList::reverse()
{
    Node *new_head = nullptr;                                       //create new head as we want it to start from last element

    for (current = head; current;)                                  //same as display, ask it to go through list from head then outside loop assign to new head and switch sides
    {
        temp = current;                                             //keep temp pointer one step behind
        current = current->next;                                    //goes through each element in the list
        temp->next = new_head;                                      //scrolls through backwards from new head
        new_head = temp;                                            
    }

    head = new_head;                                                //assign head to new head
};
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If I have written my search function correctly to do what I want it to do

Comment: You can just run through the list and search for the element.  Worst case scenario, this is O(n)... not very efficient.  You might look into implementing a binary search tree instead (searching worst case O(ln(n))).

Comment: @Ryan then why don't you test it instead of asking us?

Comment: I wanted to know if there was a more efficient way of doing a search rather than following the same path as the remove function

Comment: @TravisJ: But [how do you binary search a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5281053/10077)?

Comment: You could build it on top... sort of a hybrid linked-list and BST.  You will need to add pointers to (two) children for each element in your linked list.  For implementing a binary search tree, either google it (they are very common) or look at something like "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein.  The idea is you have a "smaller" child and a "larger" child.  You compare the element to the current node.  If it is what you're looking for done.  Otherwise you move to either the larger or smaller child (depending on whether the element is larger or smaller).

Comment: In a perfectly ideal case, half of all the remaining elements are below the smaller child (at every level) and half are below the larger child (at every level).  This is a balanced binary search tree.  If you take no thought beforehand when building the tree you will likely get a skewed tree which isn't as efficient to search.  If you are overly concerned about this, look up "red-black" trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search algorithm seems to be wrong. Change it to :

```
if (current != NULL) // (current == NULL) is wrong because it means the value wasn't found
{
    searchnumber = current;
    current = current->next;
    std::cout << "-" << searchnumber->number << " Found"; // here searchnumber is the node's address. You need to print its value, so use searchnumber->number
}
```

And you don't need to remove nodes till you find the desired value.
You can just use your search algorithm to find if a number already in the list. If that's what you want.

Comment: It works but it displays a random number instead of the number I wanted to find. E.g. 000nbn45found

Comment: `if (current == NULL)` how the hell it will show a number ??
it is null... you know what i mean... change it and i think it will show the actual numbers

Comment: And it would be great if you give the input for which your code is not working and also your full code

Comment: I have made the changes and done what you said above, if I search for a value in the list and it isn't there it works. If I search for a value in the list it also works but instead of displaying 2 for example, it displays a hex number eg 050b3ng44

Comment: edit your question and give the full code... including adding a value

Comment: Oh ! i see...
change `searchnumber = current;` to `searchnumber = current->number;` it will work

Comment: change what i said in prev comment

Comment: Int can't be assigned to node

Comment: change it to `int value = current->number;` and print the value

Comment: also you can use previous code, just change like i said in the answer

Answer (score 0):

While a list is unordered a comparison of search algorithms doesn't have any sense. Simply iterate over all nodes one by one and apply match criteria.