# Search NAME in a Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I have a linked list of `Student` nodes:

```
struct Student  
{
   char name[20];
   char Class[20];
   string reg;
   float cgpa;
   int marks;
   Student *next;

}*head,*lastptr;
```

What I want to do is to search for a `Student` by a name.

Here is my `searchStudent()` function, which is not working. I don't know what the issue is.

```cpp
Student searchStudent(){
    cout << "1. Search By Name" << endl;
    cout << "2. Lower Then CGPA" << endl;
    cout << "3. Equal To CGPA" << endl;
    cout << "4. Greater than CGPA " << endl;
    cout << "5. By Program " << endl;
    cout << "6. Exit" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    char choice;
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == '1'){
        cout << endl;
        char *name;
        cout << "You chose option #1." << endl;
        cout<<"Please enter name you want to search: " <<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout << endl << "Listing all student Students : " << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------" << endl;

        Student *current;
        current = head;

        if (current->next == NULL) //Reached end of the list
        {
            cout<<"\n name not found in the Linked List \n";
        }
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            cout<<name[20];
            cout<<current->name;
            if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0) { //found the element
                cout << current -> name << endl;
                cout << current -> Class << endl;
                cout << current -> reg << endl;
                cout << current -> cgpa << endl;
                cout << current -> marks << endl;

                current = current -> next;
                cout << endl;
            } else { //search next element
                return searchStudent();   //this will call your function again for the next element on the list
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an Image of my console App:

[image]

Comment: Why have you tagged c++11? Wasn't just c++ OK?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search Function in Linked List - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626097/search-function-in-linked-list-c)

Comment: C++ is OK but i am using C++11 ;).
Thanks i have the answer to my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *name;
cout << "You chose option #1." << endl;
cout<<"Please enter name you want to search: " <<endl;
cin>>name;
```

You are trying to read the student's name in a pointer, instead of a memory location.

Do this:

```
char name[20]; // size taken from struct definition
cout << "You chose option #1." << endl;
cout<<"Please enter name you want to search: " <<endl;
cin>>name;
```

Note: You should use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of char arrays when working on strings.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks its working but i wonder when i enter two students in Student the function returns first when i go for first one but when i search the second student it returns nothing..if you don't mind please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @SalmanhassanOkZ Please ask a different question. It is not a good practice to merge different queries in the same post.

Comment: @CinCout When reading into a fixed-length character array, you should use `std:setw`, `cin.get()`, or `cin.getline()` to ensure you don't overflow the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

You use an uninitialized pointer "name". This cause your error.

There are 3 solution:

- The simplest one is **declare name as an array** like in the struct so char name[20]
- the second one is to **use string instead of the char***. In this case you can substitute also the name variable in the struct student.
- the last is to **allocate the memory with a malloc** for the variable char* name. *But remember to use it  in the right way in cin a to deallocate memory at the end.*