# How to insert a item in sorted linked list within constant time complexity?

Tags: data-structures

I have a problem in sorted linked list .I can't insert an item in constant time. If it possible than how can i solve it?

And this function time complexity is Big-O(N)

```
template <class ItemType>
void SortedType<ItemType>::InsertItem(ItemType item)
{
  NodeType<ItemType>* newNode;
  NodeType<ItemType>* predLoc;
  NodeType<ItemType>* location;
  bool moreToSearch;

  location = listData;
  predLoc = NULL;
  moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
  while (moreToSearch)
  {
    if (location->info < item)
    {
      predLoc = location;
      location = location->next;
      moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
    }
    else moreToSearch = false;
  }
  newNode = new NodeType<ItemType>;
  newNode->info = item;

  if (predLoc == NULL)
  {
    newNode->next = listData;
    listData = newNode;
  }
  else
  {
    newNode->next = location;
    predLoc->next = newNode;
  }
  length++;
}
```

Comment: You can't. If you could do that you would have revolutionized sorting, you could start with an empty linked list, which would by definition be sorted, add the first item, still sorted, and then keep going which would mean that sorting items would be O(n), this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to inset a item in sorted linked list within constant time complexity. But you can insert item in O(log n) time complexity.

[how to apply binary search O(log n) on a sorted linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281053/how-to-apply-binary-search-olog-n-on-a-sorted-linked-list)

Comment: If you want to insert data in constant time then You have to use unsorted list, 
otherwise you have to make a new algo to insert data in sorted list in constant time.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to inset a item in sorted linked list with O(1) time complexity. You can only insert an item in unsorted linked list with time complexity O(1).
You can know more about time complixity from this link http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: If anyone want to give downvote, please comment me where is my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not possible in sorted linked list but you can insert an item in unsorted linked list with constant time that is Big-O(1).

and also see this  ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tta6BIiIIFI

Answer (score 0):

The answers are all correct, however there is some nuance to this.

You *can* insert into a list in constant time, provided you already have a hold of the node where you want to perform the insert.

See also this question: [Why do we say linked list inserts are constant time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39837093/why-do-we-say-linked-list-inserts-are-constant-time)

I came across this question because I was similarly confused after reading in Scott Meyers *Effective STL* that inserting into a list is a constant time operation. (This is a C++ text, but the principles apply to other languages such as Java.)

It is, at least the inserting part is constant time, but for an insert to be useful you *usually* have to search for the node where you want to perform the insert. (Usually just before or after that node.)

Finding, or searching might be a linear O(N) operation if your find algorithm simply searches the list from the begining to the end looking for the node of interest. Hence one may think it is an O(N) operation. Other algorithms may give better average performance than O(N).

The other answers are not wrong per-se, it just depends what you consider to be part of the "inserting" operation. Strictly speaking it is contant time - but usually that isn't very helpful, since a number of inserts is usually combined with at least one find operation, or something of that nature.