# Why do we say linked list inserts are constant time?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, time-complexity

I understand that linked list insertions are constant time due to simple rearrangement of pointers but doesn't this require knowing the element from which you're doing the insert?

And getting access to that element requires a linear search. So why don't we say that inserts are still bound by a linear search bottleneck first?

Edit: I am not talking about head or tail appends, but rather insertions anywhere in between.

Comment: Because it's usually meant that some value is inserted at position *first* or *last* (where you always got the pointers needed). Else anything you describe applies. (If you think, that this operation is kind of too simple/easy, think about doing the same on an array; in regards to complexity)

Comment: Not all inserts require searching.

Comment: Ignoring the trial head/tail cases, which I call prepending and appending, different from inserting, which occurs somewhere between head and tail

Comment: No surprises here. The question is: where did you get this idea / description? When i visit [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), everything is nicely described (colored-table).

Comment: @Sascha practically every online resource that says inserting is constant time, but ignores that you need the reference element first, which requires linear search

Comment: But then when would we ever want to use a linked list? Just for head prepends and fast inserts near the start of the list? As tail appends / near-tail inserts are still fast in array lists due to amortization and minimal shifting of suffix subarrays, respectively?

Comment: "Edit: I am not talking about head or tail appends, but rather insertions anywhere in between." This is search-and-insert, which is a different operation from just insert. It's more useful to talk about "insert" as its own operation (which is constant time) and if we need to do some other operation first then consider that other operation. Your argument basically boils down to "some people define insert as X and it's constant time, but I want to define it as Y which isn't constant time, aren't all those people wrong?" Well, no.

Comment: How can you insert though without a search? You need to know *where* you're inserting if you aren't using indexes. Otherwise you somehow need to miraculously already have the node reference ahead of time somehow.

Comment: Which brings me back to my other question of when we'd ever use a linked list outside of fast head appends.

Comment: @SeanHill in practice, extremely rarely. Even head inserts, well, just reverse your indexer and append.

Comment: @Harold When might they be used in practice?

Comment: There is actually little point to ordered insertion into a linked list. If order matters, use a tree, since ordered insertion will be cheaper. Linked list is superior when order doesn't matter, or FIFO or LIFO are the only orders that matter, in which case the insertions are truly constant.

Comment: But if order doesn't matter can't we just insert at the tail? And if we can insert at the tail, can't we get away with using an ArrayList anyway?

Comment: Did you ignore FIFO and LIFO? ArrayList just seems to be a different way of implementing List. So, go for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it requires already having a node where you're going to insert next to.

> So why don't we say that inserts are still bound by a linear search bottleneck first?

Because that isn't *necessarily* the case, if you can arrange things such that you actually do know the insertion point (not just the index, but the node).

Obviously you can "insert" at the front or end, that seems like a bit of cheat perhaps, it stretches the meaning of the word "insert" a bit. But consider an other case: while you're appending to the list, at some point you remember a node. Just any node of your choosing, using any criterium to select it that you want. Then you could easily insert after or before that node later.

That sounds like a very "constructed" situation, because it is. For a more practical case that is a lot like this (but not exactly), you could look at the Dancing Links algorithm.

Comment: But then wouldn't we have to remember all nodes if we wanted the ability to insert anywhere? Say maintaining an additional hash map of node references?

Comment: @SeanHill if that's what you need then that's what you need, no way around it. Careful with the key though, you can't make it the index, because it would change if you insert. Often you don't need everything, but it's completely legitimate to keep such extra data structures on the side.

Comment: Right,  key wouldn't be anything like index k for 0 <= k < n as those would change after an insert

Comment: If you wouldn't mind adding to your answer: In what kind of (common-in-practice) situation would we already have the node where we'd be inserting? You say "at some point you remember a node" but when would this ever occur in practice / what kind of situation? Like you're constructing the list and suddenly you come across a node with some special value so we remember it because we know we'll be inserting there later? Is what what you mean?

Comment: @SeanHill: Such as head or tail nodes...which for some reason you refuse to consider outright.

Comment: That's what I am asking though. Is the head/tail really the only context in which we'd consider a LinkedList in practice?

Comment: @SeanHill nothing actually common that I know of. I could construct examples, but let's get real here: in over a decade, I have never actually used such a technique. Actually I don't remember legitimately using a linked list for any purpose - I *do* remember replacing a couple of them with ArrayList to make it faster (they were being used in the "search-then-insert" way that you correctly identified as being a bad usage pattern)

Answer (score 4):

> Why do we say linked list inserts are constant time?

Because the *insert* operation is constant time.

Note that *locating* the position of the insert is not considered part of the *insert* operation itself. That would be a different operation, which may or may not be constant time, e.g. if including *search time*, you get:

- Insert at head: **Constant**
- Insert at tail: **Constant**
- Insert before current element while iterating<sup>1</sup>: **Constant**
- Insert at index position: **Linear**

<sup>1) Assuming you're iterating anyway.</sup>

By contrast, `ArrayList` insert operation is linear time. If including *search time*, you get:

- Insert at head: ***Linear***
- Insert at tail: **Constant** (amortized)
- Insert before current element while iterating<sup>1</sup>: ***Linear***
- Insert at index position: **Linear**

Comment: But then why can't we say ArrayList insertion is constant time... given that we ignore the linear component of moving over the rest of the array?

Comment: Also I think inserting at tail for ArrayList is technically amortized constant time and not constant time, since in rare instances a linear recopying of a larger array capacity will be needed if the current capacity isn't enough

Comment: `ArrayList` insert is linear because it has to *move* all subsequent elements to make room. That move is linear in time, i.e. depends on size of array.

Comment: Yes but I can also say "LinkedList insert is linear because it has to *acquire* the correct insertion point first. That acquisition is linear in time, i.e. depends on the number of elements in the list before the insertion point."

Comment: (I'm just pointing out that I find it strange that the linear scan is conveniently ignored when discussing LinkedLists but included when talking about the copying process of an ArrayList). Sort of like if someone says "Yes, this ice cream is free... after you pay for it."

Comment: The linear scan is not included in *either* when saying that *insert* is constant/linear. Only the *insert* operation is being discussed. You seem to be unable/unwilling to grasp that. *Insert* and *search for position* is **two different operations**. Inserting a new node in a linked list is constant, regardless of where in the list it occurs, not counting how you got to that location. Injecting a new element in an array list is linear, because it has to move remaining entries (half list size *on average*), not counting how you got to that location.

Comment: But the distinction is arbitrary. You're saying insert is different from search in a LinkedList, so why can't I say that in an ArrayList, inserting is different from the suffix array copying? Either way, k inserts are needed so that can be ignored in both cases. For LinkedList you're saying "not counting how you got to that location" but if you can say "not counting" there what stops me from saying the same thing about the copying process of ArrayList insert?

Comment: I'm giving up. We've told you many times already, and you refuse to hear. **Insert** and **Search** are two different operations. That is true for both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`. **IT IS THE SAME FOR BOTH**. Nobody is applying different rules. I'm saying "not counting" because there are **multiple ways of locating the insertion point**, and they have different run times. Once there, the "insert" operation (and only the insert operation) is considered. In an arraylist, you cannot insert without moving to make space, so it is a integral part of the *insert* and cannot be ignored.

Comment: But if you're going to make that distinction then I can easily say "If you insert at the end of an ArrayList, you CAN insert without moving to make space" so it is not INTEGRAL. I'm not trying to be difficult here: Every example you've mentioned has a clear and obvious counter-case to it that is decided as being separate in one context but not in the other.

Comment: @SeanHill: You're ignoring worst-case. Worst-case array insert is O(n). Worst-case list insert is O(1). Worst-case array linear search is O(n). Worst-case list search is O(n).

Comment: Worst case array insert is O(n) only if we are including the copying process (i.e. counting it as part of the actual insert operation).

Comment: Because the statement "insert is constant/linear" is a **general** statement. The statement doesn't address fringe conditions, even if those are fairly prevalent (add tail). In general, if you're "standing" somewhere arbitrary in the list *(search already performed)*, and you decide to insert an element, *not knowing where you are*, how fast is the insert? For `LinkedList` it is **constant**. For `ArrayList`, it has to move between `0` and `size` elements, and since we don't know where we are, *statistically* we have to move `size / 2` elements, aka **linear** to size of the list.

Answer (score 1):

The following two operations are **different**:

- Operation A: Insert anywhere in the linked list
- Operation B: Insert at a specific position in the linked list

Operation A can be achieved in `O(1)`. The new element can inserted at `head` (or `tail` if maintained and desired).

Operation B involves finding followed by inserting. The finding part is `O(n)`. The inserting is as above, i.e. `O(1)`. If, however, the result of the finding is provided as input, for example if there are APIs like

```
Node * Find(Node * head, int find_property);
Node * InsertAfter(Node * head, Node * existing_node, Node * new_node);
```

then the insert part of the operation is `O(1)`.

Comment: But in practice when would we ever have Node * existing_node if not from the result of a linear search or something similar?

Comment: `Find()` may be done through another function by other part of code. It me be that `Find()` is unconditional, but `Insert***()` is conditional.