# linked list, implement peekAt(k) method in log(k)

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity

I have been asked to design a data structure which will act like a stack, not limited in size, which will support the following methods, with given run-time restrictions.

**push(s)** - push s to the data structure - O(1)
**pop()** - remove and return the last element inserted O(1)
**middle()** - return the element (without removing) with index n/2 by insertion order where n is the current amount of elements in the data structure. - O(1)
**peekAt(k)** - return the kth element by insertion order (the bottom of the stack is k=1) - O(log(k))

the 3 methods will use a linked list, but how i should implement the method peekAt(k).

thank you.

Comment: It's better if you post some code or something you have tried.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to apply binary search O(log n) on a sorted linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281053/how-to-apply-binary-search-olog-n-on-a-sorted-linked-list)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a variant of [Skip List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), which is ordered by insertion order.

The only modification you actually need, in order to support `O(logk)` instead of `O(logn)`, is to from from down up before you initiate your search, something like:

```
// Assume head points to the first element in the lower tier list.
current = head
while (current->next->index < k) current = current->up
```

At this point, the element you are looking for is somewhere between `current` and `current->next`. You can look it up using a regular skip list search for the value `k`, starting from `current` instead of the top tier.

Note that finding `current` is done in `O(logk)`, because, you basically check iteratively:

```
1 < k ?
2 < k ?
4 < k ?
8 < k ?
...
2^ceil(logk) < k ?
```

Which is, O(log(k)) checks.

Comment: alright thanks. but how do i keep the O(1) time complexity to the other methods?

Comment: @שליולוי: Since you only add elements to the top (last element of the skip list), you connect it to the previous element in each tier at probability `1/2^tier`. Which means, bottom tier: 2^0=1, then 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 and so on. This means, each insertion is costing `1+1/2+1/4+...  < 2`, which is constant. Removal is similar. Median is staying the same.