# Binary Search on a Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

It is possible to perform binary search on a doubly-linked list in Θ(log ) time?

My answer is yes because if the list is already somewhat ordered it could be faster than just O(n).

Comment: Are you talking about *searching* or *sorting*?

Comment: No....................

Comment: It is possible but completely pointless. A linear search would be quicker. Binary search really demands an array, or at least a directly-indexable data structure.

Comment: See also [how to apply binary search O(log n) on a sorted linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281053/how-to-apply-binary-search-olog-n-on-a-sorted-linked-list) I'll grant that it is not a full duplicate since it addresses singly-linked lists, and the current question specifies doubly-linked. (The accepted answer to the other question would need to be adapted -- maybe made more complicated -- to apply to doubly-linked lists, even though the conclusion would be the same.)

Comment: Visiting a node and not looking at the key is pointless ***if*** key comparison is constant effort. Conceivably, it does *not* depend on the number of items.

Answer (score 5):

In order to do a binary search on a doubly-linked list, you're going to have to first iterate to the halfway-point of the list, so that you can do your first recursion on the two halves of the list.

Iterating to the halfway-point of a linked list is already an O(n) operation, since the time it takes to iterate to the halfway-point will grow linearly as the list itself gets longer.

So you're already at O(n) time, even before you've done any actual searching.  Hence, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked the question, the answer is no.  You cannot have O(lg(n)) *time* for a linked list since traversal is linear, it cannot be better than O(n) in general, but binary search would be worse than a linear scan in that case since it must iterate multiple times to "jump" around.  It would be better to do a single linear scan to find the element.

However, the C++ standard specifies that `std::lower_bound` algorithm (which does a binary search) has the following complexity:

> [lower.bound]
>
> Complexity: At most log2(last - first) + O(1) comparisons and projections.

That is, it is counting the element *comparisons*, not time, if you are measuring time by number of iterator advancements.  That is, it finds the proper place by calling `std::advance()` on an iterator many times, but each of those calls on a list will be O(N) iterator advancements but on random access containers it's a constant, and for each call to `advance` there would be a corresponding call to the comparator.

That's why it is always so important to be clear what big-oh notation is measuring.  Often the comparisons are a proxy for time, but not always!

Comment: But the next line says " However, for non-LegacyRandomAccessIterators, the number of iterator increments is linear." so O(N).